# Selected webmap does not contain any layers that can be used as data sources for ArcGIS Operations Dashboard?

Tags: web-mapping, arcgis-portal, operations-dashboard

I'm new to ESRI ArcGIS applications and at the moment I'm trying to learn the operations dashboard. I looked at their tutorial and it is fairly easy as they've provided data.

Now, I'm trying to use my own data. What I did was create a web map, I then pull and load my CSV files to create the layers. Everything looks nice and I saved the web map.

When I try to open it in the operations dashboard I get `the selected webmap does not contain any layers that can be used as data sources` at the data source tab.

What am I doing wrong?

Can someone guide me because I can't use the other widgets if I can't view the data sources.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your layers are not in one of the supported formats. According to a post on the [ArcGIS website](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/operations-dashboard/windows-desktop/author/data-sources.htm) only hosted feature layers etc. can be used as data sources:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make an event layer of your .csv's within ArcMap, export those to a shapefile/feature class, then publish those as my hosted services. Within your my content tab, add your feature layers to a webmap, save that webmap. Open Dashboard, add that webmap, and your layers should be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have uploaded your CSV files, you can open the item and convert them to hosted feature services..  These will then work fine in Ops Dashboard.